# Spark standalone connection driver to worker

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit, apache-spark-standalone

I'm trying to host locally a spark standalone cluster. I have two heterogeneous machines connected on a LAN. Each piece of the architecture listed below is running on docker.
I have the following configuration

- master on machine 1 (port 7077 exposed)
- worker on machine 1
- driver on machine 2

I use a test application that opens a file and counts its lines.
The application works when the file replicated on all workers and I use `SparkContext.readText()`

But when when the file is only present on worker while I'm using `SparkContext.parallelize()` to access it on workers, I have the following display :

````
INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20180116210619-0007/4 on hostPort 172.17.0.3:6598 with 4 cores, 1024.0 MB RAM
INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20180116210619-0007/4 is now RUNNING
INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20180116210619-0007/4 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Executor app-20180116210619-0007/4 removed: Command exited with code 1
INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20180116210619-0007/5 on worker-20180116205132-172.17.0.3-6598 (172.17.0.3:6598) with 4 cores```
````

that goes on and on again without actually computing the app.

This is working when I put the driver on the same pc as the worker. So I guess there is some kind of connection to permit between so two across the network. Are you aware of a way to do that (which ports to open, which adress to add in /etc/hosts ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR** Make sure that `spark.driver.host:spark.driver.port` can be accessed from each node in the cluster.

In general you have ensure that all nodes (both executors and master) can reach the driver.

- In the cluster mode, where driver runs on one of the executors this is satisfied by default, as long as no ports are closed for the connections (see below).
- In client mode machine, on which driver has been started, has to be accessible from the cluster. It means that `spark.driver.host` has to resolve to a publicly reachable address.

In both cases you have to keep in mind, that by default driver runs on a random port. It is possible to use a fixed one by setting `spark.driver.port`. Obviously this doesn't work that well, if you want to submit multiple applications at the same time.

Furthermore:

> when when the file is only present on worker

won't work. All inputs have to be accessible from driver, as well as, from each executor node.

Comment: Thank to your answer, I think the issue is with communications between docker containers across network.

Comment: I finally started my drivers and worker dockers with `--net=host` option and it worked. This is only a temp solution as it doesn't give me network isolation. I'm now studying docker to find a proper solution.

Comment: Hi @user6910411 - for some reason when I start the sparkContext from my local machine to a remote spark cluster, the value for spark.driver.host is the local IP of my machine which is obviously not reachable from the worker node. How can this be resolved?

Comment: @nEO `spark.driver.host` (and optionally `spark.driver.bindAddress`).